# Pivot two columns and keep the values same in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a query to get different time types and hours

```
SELECT calc_time.hours             measure,
       calc_time.payroll_time_type elements,
       calc_time.person_id,
       calc_time.start_time
FROM   hwm_tm_rep_work_hours_sum_v calc_time,
       per_all_people_f papf
WHERE  grp_type_id = 200
AND    payroll_time_type IN ( 'Afternoon shift',
                             'TL',
                             'Evening shift',
                             'Regular Pay ',
                             'OT' )
AND    (To_date(To_char(calc_time.start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN To_date(To_char(:From_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND To_date( To_char(:To_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD' ))
AND    papf.person_id = calc_time.person_id
```

I get the output like -

```
Start_time     person_id                 elements            measure
01-Jan-2021     198                     Regular Pay           10
01-Jan-2021     198                       OT                  2
01-jAN-2021     198                     Afternoon shift       2
16-JAN-2021     198                     Regular Pay           10
17-JAN-2021     198                     OT                    3
20-JAN-2021     198                     EVENING SHIFT         8


08-JAN-2021     11                      Regular Pay           8
09-JAN-2021     11                        OT                  1
08-JAN-2021     11                          tl                2
10-JAN-2021     12                      Evening shift         9
11-JAN-2021     12                     Evening shift         9
```

I want this output to be dispplayed as follows WITHIN TWO DATES THAT I PASS AS PARAMETER - LIKE PARAMETER TO AND FROM DATE 01-JAN-2021 AND 31-JAN-2021

```
 person_id        Regular_pay       OT          OTHER_MEASURE               OTHER_CODE
   198                   20           5             2                       Afternoon shift
   198                   20           5             8                     EVENING SHIFT
   11                     8           1             2                           TL
   12                                               18                        Evening shift
```

So sum of Regular pay and OT IN separate columns and all others in other_measure and other_code

How can I tweak the main query to achieve this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.person_id,
         SUM(CASE c.payroll_time_type WHEN 'Regular Pay' THEN SUM(c.hours) END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY c.person_id) AS regular_pay,
         SUM(CASE c.payroll_time_type WHEN 'OT' THEN SUM(c.hours) END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY c.person_id) AS OT,
         SUM(c.hours) AS other_measure,
         c.payroll_time_type AS Other_code
  FROM   hwm_tm_rep_work_hours_sum_v c
         INNER JOIN per_all_people_f p
         ON (p.person_id = c.person_id)
  WHERE  grp_type_id = 200
  AND    payroll_time_type IN (
           'Afternoon shift',
           'TL',
           'Evening shift',
           'Regular Pay',
           'OT'
         )
  AND    c.start_time >= TRUNC(:from_date)
  AND    c.start_time <  TRUNC(:to_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  GROUP BY
         c.person_id,
         c.payroll_time_type
)
WHERE   other_code NOT IN ('Regular Pay', 'OT');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hwm_tm_rep_work_hours_sum_v (start_time, person_id, payroll_time_type, hours) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 198, 'Regular Pay',     10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 198, 'OT',               2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 198, 'Afternoon shift',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-16', 198, 'Regular Pay',     10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-17', 198, 'OT',               3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-20', 198, 'Evening shift',    8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-08',  11, 'Regular Pay',      8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-09',  11, 'OT',               1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-08',  11, 'TL',               2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-10',  12, 'Evening shift',    9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-11',  12, 'Evening shift',    9 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE per_all_people_f (person_id, grp_type_id) AS
SELECT 198, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  11, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  12, 200 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PERSON_ID | REGULAR_PAY | OT | OTHER_MEASURE | OTHER_CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 8 | 1 | 2 | TL |
> | 12 |  |  | 18 | Evening shift |
> | 198 | 20 | 5 | 2 | Afternoon shift |
> | 198 | 20 | 5 | 8 | Evening shift |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46a62539e1c955aebfebdd8887672efe)*

Comment: the calculation of SUM(c.hours)  in other_measure is not correctly when I am using the exact query. It is givng me the sum of all other columns other than regular pay/OT

Comment: @Sree Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70266439/edit) your question with a [MRE] including the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data **that represents the problem**; and your expected output for that sample data. This query generates the exact output you requested in the question; if your data is different then you have not asked a question with representative data and how do you expect us to provide an answer that solves the problem which you have not shown to us?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this - In your question, unfortunately, it is not clear in which table which columns/values ​​are available.

```
SELECT 
  calc_time.person_id,
  (select sum(calc_time.start_time) FROM hwm_tm_rep_work_hours_sum_v calc_time where papf.person_id = calc_time.person_id and calc_time.payroll_time_type = 'Regular Pay') as Regular_Pay,
...
FROM   hwm_tm_rep_work_hours_sum_v calc_time,
       per_all_people_f papf
WHERE  grp_type_id = 200
AND    payroll_time_type IN ( 'Afternoon shift',
                             'TL',
                             'Evening shift',
                             'Regular Pay ',
                             'OT' )
AND    (
              To_date(To_char(calc_time.start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN To_date(To_char(:From_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
              AND    To_date( To_char(:To_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) )
and  papf.person_id = calc_time.person_id

-- use a group by
GROUP BY
  calc_time.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use aggregation and then apply [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) clause to calculate the required columns. Below is the code with comments, assuming you can manage filter by dates.

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> PERSON_ID | ELEMENTS        | MEASURE
> --------: | :-------------- | ------:
>       198 | Regular Pay     |       1
>       198 | Regular Pay     |       2
>       198 | Afternoon shift |       3
>       198 | Afternoon shift |       4
>       198 | OT              |       5
>       198 | OT              |       6
>       198 | EVENING SHIFT   |       7
>       198 | EVENING SHIFT   |       8
>        11 | Regular Pay     |      11
>        11 | Regular Pay     |      12
>        11 | TL              |      13
>        11 | TL              |      14
>        11 | EVENING SHIFT   |      15
>        11 | EVENING SHIFT   |      16
>        12 | TL              |      21
>        12 | TL              |      22
>        12 | EVENING SHIFT   |      23
>        12 | EVENING SHIFT   |      24
> ```

> ```
> select
>   person_id,
>   ot,
>   regular_pay,
>   elements as other_code,
>   mes as other_measure
> from (
>   /*First you need to aggregate all the measures by person_id and code*/
>   select
>     person_id,
>     elements,
>     sum(measure) as mes
>   from t
>   /*Date filter goes here*/
>   group by
>     person_id,
>     elements
> )
> model
>   /*RETURN UPDATED ROWS
>    will do the trick,
>   because we'll update only "other"
>   measures, so OT and Regular pay will no go
>   to the output*/
>   return updated rows
>   /*Where to break the calculation*/
>   partition by (person_id)
>   /*To be able to reference by code*/
>   dimension by (elements)
>   measures (
>     mes,
>     0 as ot,
>     0 as regular_pay
>   )
>   rules upsert (
>     ot[
>       elements not in ('OT', 'Regular Pay')
>     ] = sum(mes)['OT'],
>     regular_pay[
>       elements not in ('OT', 'Regular Pay')
>     ] = sum(mes)['Regular Pay']
>   )
> ```

> ```
> PERSON_ID |   OT | REGULAR_PAY | OTHER_CODE      | OTHER_MEASURE
> --------: | ---: | ----------: | :-------------- | ------------:
>       198 |   11 |           3 | EVENING SHIFT   |            15
>       198 |   11 |           3 | Afternoon shift |             7
>        11 | null |          23 | TL              |            27
>        11 | null |          23 | EVENING SHIFT   |            31
>        12 | null |        null | TL              |            43
>        12 | null |        null | EVENING SHIFT   |            47
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c336eb8099fec8e72b7995bcc27c0262)*